# How to bind redux dispatch method to a "dumb" component

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

I have a Logout component that just renders a button that should dispatch a logout action to the reducer. How can I bind the dispatch method to that component without using redux connect(...)? or is the best way to use connect() even if it's a dumb component like this one?

my component looks like this and I make the dispatch method available by importing the store but it doesn't feel right:

```
import React from "react";
import { userActions } from '../_actions';
import { store } from '../_helpers/store.js';

const LogoutButton = ({ history }) => (
    <button
        type="button"
        className="logout"
        onClick={() => {
            store.dispatch(userActions.logout());
            history.push(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/signin`);
        }
    }>
    Logout
    </button>
);

export default LogoutButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connect` should be the way to go whether its a Functional component or a conventional React component. The other advantage that you get with connect is that it is a `PureComponent` and hence takes care of updates

```
const LogoutButton = ({ history }) => (
    <button
        type="button"
        className="logout"
        onClick={() => {
            userActions.logout();
            history.push(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/signin`);
        }
    }>
    Logout
    </button>
);

export default connect(null, userActions)(LogoutButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't feel right yes. You'd better use the convenient way with `connect`. Have in mind that relying on the module system to deliver `dispatch` or data from the store will potentially make your testing difficult. If you use `connect` those stuff will come from React's context and you can easily mock them up.

Answer (score 1):

A dumb component should be driven by props, So you can just pass a function as a prop in your `LoginButton` component form your container component.

Example:

Parent:

```
<LoginButton onPress={store.dispatch(userActions.logout())}/>
```

Child:

```
const LogoutButton = ({ history, onPress }) => (
 <button
    type="button"
    className="logout"
    onClick={() => {
        onPress();
        history.push(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/signin`);
    }
 }>
 Logout
 </button>
);
```

Comment: I like that! Thanks